# keycode for ctrl

Tags: java, jtree, keycode

For multiple selection in a Jtree,I am using multiple selection mode in it.It works.But I want to know when i am making multiple selection exactly in this tree to do this i wrote a very simple keycontroller class that implements KeyListener, but i wanna check whether <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is pressed or not to do so i am using this code but it seems to be not working :

```
kc.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK ;
```

what is the keyCode for ctrl ? Or am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

As <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is a key mask, there is no character for the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key alone.

However, according to [KeyEvent](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) documentation, there is always a vaild key code that is sent when either a key is pressed or released. in that case, it should be `KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED` and `getModifiersEx()` should return true for the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key. Notice that, for it to work, you have to register a [KeyListener](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) (specially handle for both keyPressed() and keyReleased()).

Comment: Is there a way to understand that i am making multiple selection in a spesific slection.I mean i dont want to lose the previous selected item,when i am making multiple selection.

Answer (score 1):

The key code for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is `KeyCode.VK_CONTROL`. In order to find if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is held you can do this:

```
if ((event.getModifiers() & ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK) ==ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK) {
System.out.println("CTRL KEY PRESSED");
}
```

Which is using the `java.awt.event.ActionEvent`instead of the `java.awt.event.KeyEvent`. So the code for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in `ActionEvent` is `CTRL_MASK`.

Hope this helps.